# Attempting to install Media Wiki on IIS - config takes minutes to load

Tags: iis, mediawiki

I'm trying to install MediaWiki using IIS on Windows 2000 server. I've extracted the files to a location whereby I can see the startpage on startpage/index.php, however when I click to "set up the wiki" (startpage/mw-config/index.php), the next page takes around 10-15 minutes to load.

I can see the header and the sourcecode right away, but the page itself does not show up for at least 10 minutes. I've tried copying the sourcecode into an html file and saved it at startpage/mw-config/index.html but it still takes the same amount of time. My set-up meets all the requirements for MediaWiki.

I've tried making changes to the output_buffering and the register_globals in the php.ini file  as suggested when searching for slow php/iis loading times, however it doesn't seem to make any difference.

I'm logged in as a normal user, not an admin user, could that be an issue? Otherwise I'm at a loss to why the page is loading, but taking 15 mins to load when the sourcecode is available right away.

Thanks

Comment: Do you see the closing </html> in page source? If yes, what component of this page is loading for so long (use Firebug to find out)?

Comment: Yes, I can see </html> at the end of the page source. I've gone through section by section and it looks like only a single line makes the loading time go from minutes to 1 second:  
`<link rel="stylesheet" href="/mw-config/index.php/mw-config/index.php?css=ltr" />`  
I've also had a look in the css mentioned in the link and tried to identify which section was causing the slowdown. However, no single section when removed speeded up the site loading time.

Comment: Using Firebug, I just discovered this component returned a "CGI Application Timeout" error which was not visible on the page - this looks like the issue to investigate.

Comment: `/mw-config/index.php/mw-config/index.php` looks interesting. What's your installer's URL?

Comment: I completely missed that it was duplicating. Removing one of the duplicates in firebug caused the page to load normally. The page I use to access the wiki installation is just Wikiname/ (or when I disabled the default document in IIS, Wikiname/index.php). I'm not sure what could be causing the duplication, and a quick google for the problem line doesn't show any results. I'll have to have a more thorough look in the php files.

Comment: @Ana, did you in the end?

Answer (score 0):

Ana's solution: I completely missed that it was duplicating `/mw-config/index.php/mw-config/index.php. Removing one of the duplicates in firebug caused the page to load normally.